# Custom option value in select

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

i am using a angular to populate an selectInput, but i want to use a "Custom" values in the option value

My current output

```
<select ng-change="getModels(selected.id)" ng-model="selected" ng-options="category.name for category in categories">
    <option value="0">red</option>
    <option value="1">green</option>
    <option value="2">yellow</option>
</select>
```

My Json

```
$scope.categories = [
    {id:1000, name:red}
    {id:2000, name:green}
    {id:3000, name:yellow}
}
```

and i want this output:

```
<select>
    <option value="1000">red</option>
    <option value="2000">green</option>
    <option value="3000">yellow</option>
</select>
```

Comment: What's wrong with your current approach? Seems like it's the way to go with `selected` set to the actual `category` object

Answer (score 0):

You can use `track by` expression like this:

```
<select 
    ng-options="category.id as category.name for category in categories track by category.id"
    ng-model="selected">
</select>
```

Please see this [jFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kno16c8L/).